# How do I save a MS Word 2008 document as a PDF with valid hyperlinks on OSX

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, microsoft-word, pdf

I am trying to save a Word document as a PDF using MS Word 2008 for the Mac.

The document contains a bunch of hyperlinks, which work correctly from inside Microsoft Word.

When I save the document as a PDF, the hyperlinks come in as underlined blue text, but Adobe Acrobat Reader does not open the links when clicked.  I also tried using Apple Preview, which also could not open the links.  I have tried both the "Save As" PDF option and the PDF menu from inside the Print dialog.  Neither are working for me.

System Info

- MS Word:12.2.8
- OS: Snow Leopard 10.6.5

Answer (score 0):

I'm obviously missing something here since the site is for power users and other bright sparks, but I use Office 2008 and I've just saved a .doc file (with hyperlinks, which later work fine) as a PDF by opening it in Text Edit, then clicking 'Save as PDF' on the drop down file menu. You knew that of course. Sadly it's the fullest extent of  my knowledge, but the fact that it's true, and judging by the phrasing of the question, I suspect Adobe's inability to read them is the real problem. Adobe 10 for certain has had a number of problems in this area, or so I hear. Why not use the built-in PDF reader?

Sorry if this isn't what you need.

Comment: Can you explain your answer more fully?  When I open the .doc file in TextEdit, and use "Save as PDF" from the File menu, the resulting PDF shows blue underlined text that is not actually hyperlinked.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to Adobe about this last year sometime and was told they could NOT preserve hyperlinks from a Microsoft Word doc (on Mac) to PDF because Microsoft had not enabled something to allow this.

(FYI I create fully hyperlinked PDF's from Microsoft Word docs on my Windows PC all the time and it works fine ... it seems this is simply not available on the MAC) ... love to be proven wrong as I'm interested in created fully hyperlinked docs from Excel, Visio and other applications as well.)